# Combining two Lua scripts?

Tags: lua, logitech

I'm trying to find a way to combine these two scripts:

```
    function OnEvent(event, arg)
      OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
      if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
      elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
        ReleaseMouseButton(2)  -- to prevent it from being stuck on
      end
      if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5) then
        recoilx2 = not recoilx2
        spot = not spot
      end
      if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoilx2) then
        if recoilx2 then
          repeat
            MoveMouseRelative(0, 25)
            Sleep(1000)
          until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
      end

      if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
        repeat
          PressMouseButton(1)
          Sleep(15)
          ReleaseMouseButton(1)
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
      end
    end
```

When I press mouse 5 to activate the first section, the repeating click section at the bottom doesn't work.

Comment: I only see one Lua script.

Comment: Do you only press mouse 5? Because the lower if statements only run if mouse 1 is pressed - at least that's how I read the code.

Comment: As a side note: I would replace the `if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then repeat ....` part with `while IsMouseButtonPressed(1) do <whatever> end` for readability

Comment: ya currently, if i dont press mouse 5, the auto click is always on. if i press mouse 5 it only does that part of the script and not auto click. im trying to make it where nothing happens, UNLESS i press mouse 5, then BOTH happen at the same time: auto click while dragging down.

Answer (score 0):

> When I press mouse 5 to activate the first section, the repeating
>   click section at the bottom doesn't work.

When you press button 5 the first time you end up in this conditional statement

```
 if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5) then
   recoilx2 = not recoilx2
   spot = not spot
 end
```

This will assign `true` to `recoilx2`.

When you press button 1 after that you'll end up in this conditional statement:

```
if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoilx2) then
  if recoilx2 then
    repeat
      MoveMouseRelative(0, 25)
      Sleep(1000)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
  end
end
```

Here you wait until button 1 is not pressed anymore.

Unless you press button 5 again to assign `false` to `recoilx2` you'll always end up there when you press button 1 and stay there until you release button 1.

Hence you can never enter this conditional statement.

```
 if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
   repeat
     PressMouseButton(1)
     Sleep(15)
     ReleaseMouseButton(1)
   until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
 end
```

Comment: okay that makes sense to me. if i remove the recoilx2 = not recoilx2
   spot = not spot will i be able to use both at the same time?